# Get Model object from View MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have this controller

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Guest guest = new Guest;
        //add some values to guest object
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult MyFunc(Guest guest)
    {
        return PartialView("Partial1", guest);
    }
}
```

`Partial1.cshtml` is a strongly typed partial view, so is `Index.cshtml`
I need to access the same 'guest' object passed to index view in partial view.

Here is how my `Index.cshtml` view looks like:

```html
@model MyProject.Models.Guest
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/myjquery.js"></script>
<body>
    <p> Some Text </p>
    <div id="mydiv" data-model="@Model"></div>
</body>
```

And contents of myjquery.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = "/Home/MyFunc";
    var model = $("#mydiv").attr("data-model");

    $("#mydiv").load(url, model, function(response, status, xhr){
        if(status != "success"){
            $("#mydiv").html('Failed to load more content');
        }
    });
});
```

Contents of Partial1.cshtml

```cs
<p> Some Text from Partial </p>
```

Now, i can't access 'model' object from `js`. When i run it in debugger, it shows the object to be undefined. 
Kindly Help.

I'm using VS2012, Razor view engine and MVC4

**EDIT:**

Guest.cs

```cs
public class Guest
{
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with you need to pass the guest object to your view

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Guest guest = new Guest();
        //add some values to guest object
        return View(guest );
    }

    public ActionResult MyFunc(Guest guest)
    {
        return PartialView("Partial1", guest);
    }
}
```

In order for the jquery to understand your guest object, you need to convert it to JSON:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-model="@Json.Encode(@Model)"></div>
```

The following script will send the guest object back and get the PartialView result

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var url = "/Home/MyFunc";
        var model = $("#mydiv").attr("data-model");


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/MyFunc',
            data: model,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache: false,  
            success: function(data, status, settings)  
            {
                $("#mydiv").html(data);
            },
            error: function (ajaxrequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                $("#mydiv").html('Failed to load more content');
            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: I have a query though, i have been trying to do the same thing in my larger project but it cannot find `MyFunc()` method. Works fine when code is simple. What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the name of your controller in the larger project? You need to change the url to match the name of the controller.

   'public class MyNameController : Controller {
       public ActionResult MyFunc(Guest guest)'

would use

    'url: "/MyName/MyFunc",'

Comment: Name of my controller is `HomePROJController`. Yes, i adjusted the url in the `.js` when i used your code earlier, but it was not working. I have been trying to work it out ever since, still trying.

Comment: Try
 url: '/HomePROJ/MyFunc'

Comment: Yes Martin, i made that edit when i used your code, it's not working.
Additionally, i separated the function into `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` and the `GET` request is working only when typed in the url so i think url is not the problem.

Comment: Also, i placed breakpoints in the `.js`, breakpoint is being hit successfully. I'm also get the `model` object in the `.js`. I have also tried to make different versions of `MyFunc` accepting `int`, `string`, `Guest`, parameter less.. none of them are hit.

Comment: I am not sure why. To use Get request you need to change  "type: 'POST'," to "type: 'GET',". I recommend creating another question with posting your current code

Comment: Oh, please don't misunderstand me. I just was using `GET` to debug the the url. I thought additional info would help you to figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to use your browser debug tools (F12) to see what calls are being made to the server

Comment: Yes, call to the server looks like `POST localhost:4988/Home/MyFunc 404 Not Found` in console window

Comment: @Adze make sure you have not marked your MyFunc with [HttpGet] attribute. And make sure your routeValues in routeConfig are set properly.

Comment: I have not marked `MyFunc` with any attribute. Yes, how to check if the values in routeConfig are set properly or not? I too suspect it has some problem.

Comment: @Martin Kindly suggest something. I can easily see the partial view if i type the url in the address bar, but same is not working via `.js`

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I have defined **`Guest`** model as follows:

```
 public class Guest
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
 }
```

Then created this action methods:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Guest guest = new Guest();
        return View(guest);
    }

    public ActionResult MyFunc(Guest guest)
    {
        return PartialView("_Partial1", guest);
    }
```

Then your **Index.chtml** would look like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script> //it is better to add it in <head> of your Master Page (_Layout.chtml).

@model YourProject.Models.Guest


<p>Some Text </p>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
{                                
    HttpMethod = "POST",                                
    UpdateTargetId = "mydiv",                                  
    Url = Url.Action("MyFunc")
}))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id); 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName);   
    <input type="submit"/>   
}
```

And your **_Partial1.chtml**:

```
@model YourProject.Models.Guest

<p> Some Text from Partial </p>

@Model.Name
<br/>
@Model.Id 
<br/>
@Model.UserName
```

**Don't forget to include**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

One more thing to make it work that you have to add in your **Web.config** file

```
`<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` between `<appSettings>` property.
```

And yes I gave you my local reference to unobrtusive.ajax-min.js. This .js file included automatically when you create ASP.NET MVC project 'Basic' template in your Scripts folder. If you did not use this timplate you can download it from **Nuget** gallery, or just google it and find it and inlude it in your project. And understand that 'jquery.min.js' and 'jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js' are **two different files**. I hope this helps.

Comment: I have been trying to adapt your answer, but can't seem to make it work. Could you try running it once?

Comment: @Adze please could you edit your question and add definition of Guest object?

Comment: It redirects me to partial view instead of updating the element. The script you are referring to `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` must be on your PC right? Then how can i include it, as you have given local reference. I am currently using `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` this script, which is from Google's CDN

Comment: Okay, i did what you said. Now when i click submit button, it redirects me to the partial view, not updating the div.

Comment: @Adze, this could happen if you: 1)have not included <script src="[somepath]/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"
type="text/javascript"></script> in your view, or included it after your Ajax.BeginForm() helper method. So make sure you include .js file before Ajax.BeginForm(). 2)You did not add <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" /> in your Web.config file betweeb <appSettings> </appSettings>. 3) Javascript is disabled in your browser.

Comment: So make sure you configured 'Ajax.BeginForm()' helper method properly. And as I review your previous comment, understand that 'jquery.min.js' and 'jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js' are two different files. 

In my project it works perfectly fine. I am using ASP.NET MVC 4, VS2012.

Comment: Yes, i have rechecked everything you said. I had to include `jquery.min.js` otherwise it doesn't identify jquery. So there are two script calls in the `<head>`

Comment: Try to change the parameters of AjaxBeginForm(). I updated the post. And another issue why this happens is that you did not include Url.Action = ("MyFunc");